# Why this code in C++ doesn't work?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
vector<vector<int> > v(4);

vector<int> k(4,0);

for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    v.push_back(k);

for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<k.size(); j++)
        cout << v[i][j];
    cout << endl;
```

I think it should work but the program doesn't execute anything. Where am I wrong?

Comment: you need a main function....

Comment: I posted only the code in the main function without it :)

Comment: v.size() is continuously growing, so when you push back you increase the size, I will never hit the size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forever looping in the first for loop, I think something like what you want to do is:

```
int main() {
    // I think this is what your first for loop is trying to construct.
    vector<vector<int>> v(4, vector<int>(4));

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

When you `push_back` it's adding a new one to the end each time (so you had 4, then 5, then 6, then so on...).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    v.push_back(k);
```

v.size will continue to increase and the loop will run until you are out of memory!!!